# Debugging phonegap app in netbeans

Tags: debugging, cordova, netbeans

I want to make phonegap app in netbeans 8.0
I have my tablet connected with USB and I can run my app on tablet from netbeans.
Problem is that I can't debug. All console.log massages are ignored in netbeans.
How can I have debug infos in netbeans?

Comment: not sure about netbeans but you can you use the chrome inspector by turning on `usb debugging` on the device and then open chrome and browse to `chrome://inspect/`. When your app is running you will see it listed as a source under the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left some details. What OS (Android, iOS...)? Which OS version? What Cordova version do you have?

For Android, you must have Android 4.4+ and then you will be able to debug Cordova application (NetBeans does not support Phonegap). Now important is also version of Cordova. With Cordova 3.3, nothing else is needed. However with Cordova 3.4, the android manifest file has changed and it was too late to handle this change in NetBeans 8.0. Have a look at this [issue 242320](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242320) how to enable debugging with Cordova 3.4+ in NetBeans 8.0

Now if you have iOS, you need to be on Mac and have proper iOS developer certificate.

Comment: I have Android 4.1 device and cordova 3.2

Comment: This means I cannot debug?

Comment: Not that easily and certainly not within NetBeans. With Android 4.4+ (supported in Cordova 3.3+), the web view component used to display html files in Cordova application is based on Chromium, so webkit debugging is easy. With older Android, this is not possible. However you can relatively easy setup loggin of the console.log() etc. , look at http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/5/10/Setting-up-console-debugging-for-PhoneGap-and-Android